# Magento 2 empty shopping cart showing shipping & total blocks on cart page?

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart, shopping, issue, magento2-4-5

I don't want to show the Apply Coupon, Shipping Method, Total & Proceed to Checkout Button when the shopping cart is empty.

You can check the below screenshot for the same.
[image]

Please provide your input on this.